# Troubleshooting Plugins.php HTTP install path vs. a HTTPS for a single Plug-In

Tags: plugins, https

I am attempting to troubleshoot the install path showing up in Plugins.php for a plug-in I have installed on my site that I did not originally write. All resources referenced and installed by this plug-in come up as mixed content HTTP when the rest of my site is HTTPS.

I have been playing around with the code segment below but it doesn't seem to be making a difference and resolving the issue. Can someone point out what I am missing?

```
    /**
     * registers scripts and stylesheets
     */
    public function register_assets() {
        $theme = strtolower( get_option( 'wp-plugintheme', 'default') );

        // scripts
        wp_register_script( 'wpa-functions', plugins_url() . 'resources/scripts/wpa-functions.js' );
        wp_register_script( 'wpa-custom', WPA_PLUGIN_URL . 'resources/scripts/wpa-custom.js' );
    }
```

I know the edits I am making are taking affect as well as I have been able to add extra `\` s to the path.

```
    /**
     * Creates plugin globals and manages version number
     */
    public function setup() {
        // define global variables
        if (!defined('WPA_THEME_DIR') )
            define('WPA_THEME_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content/themes/' . get_template() );

        if (!defined('WPA_PLUGIN_NAME') )
            define('WPA_PLUGIN_NAME', trim(dirname(plugin_basename(__FILE__) ), '/') );

        if (!defined('WPA_PLUGIN_DIR') )
            define('WPA_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . WPA_PLUGIN_NAME . '/');

        if (!defined('WPA_PLUGIN_URL') )
            define('WPA_PLUGIN_URL', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . WPA_PLUGIN_NAME . '/');

        if (!defined('WPA_PLUGIN_BASENAME') )
            define('WPA_PLUGIN_BASENAME', plugin_basename(__FILE__) );
```

But I still continue to get these:
    `Blocked loading mixed active content http://website.org/wp-content/plugins/wp-plugintheme/resources/scripts/wpa-functions.js?ver=4.0.1`

Any help or thoughts as to what I can do short of Forcing SSL just for this one plug-in?

Comment: Have you tried to just put in the full secure url? Ex: 
`wp_register_script( 'wpa-functions','https://website.org/wp-content/plugins/wp-plugintheme/resources/scripts/wpa-functions.js?ver=4.0.1');`

Comment: I did try that but it only address some of them and really hoping to find the non-hard coding paths solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of my problem was none of the above and it was a change in the way Wordpress internal variables worked.

The plug-in I was attempting to troubleshoot was utilizing the following:

```
define('WPA_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/' . WPA_PLUGIN_NAME);
define('WPA_PLUGIN_URL', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/' . WPA_PLUGIN_NAME);
```

New Code which per these two links stating to [do not use the internal Wordpress variables](https://wordpress.org/ideas/topic/wp_plugin_url-doesnt-take-ssl-into-account) and to [use these instead](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) took care of it in the primary plugin PHP file.

```
define('WPA_PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
define('WPA_PLUGIN_URL', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ));
```

Checking the Wordpress codex was what I needed to do to determine methods were being used and the forums were helpful. I since found several plugins I previously stopped using due to SSL issues were doing something similar.